# Migrated (Manually) iOS Swift project from 1.1 to 1.2 - compiler takes more than 10 mins

Tags: ios, swift

I was working on iOS Swift project which was on Swift 1.1 compiler. I decided to convert the full project to Swift 1.2.

I was working with HanekeSwift and as well as Alamofire as third party libraries. Since I needed to support this app, iOS 7 and above I had to use iOS 7 compatible version of HanekeSwift(https://github.com/eyeballz/HanekeSwift). For crash reporting I have used crashlytics.

After about one hour of effort I could manually migrated the full project to Swift 1.2. After freeing all the errors, when I start building the project, it compiles all the file successfully but it doesn't stop the compiling.

After about 10 mins time it gives the following error:
"**Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9**". I checked all the transcript by expanding it and it doesn't show any issue.

When I check the "**Report Navigator**" it show green circle icon with white arrow inside for all the files, but only one file shows the gray circle icon and it shows as the compiling is in progress.

I couldn't find any compile time errors in that file and I'm not sure what is really happening there.

Anyone has any idea?

Edited:
I tried adding all the file to a project created using xCode 6.4, but the issue is same.

Edited:
I have a class like below:

```
import Foundation

class VehicleDetailsUpdateRequest
{
    var vin : NSString
    var vehicleId : NSNumber
    var make : NSString
    var model : NSString
    var body : NSString
    var engine: NSString
    var trim:NSString
    var fuelType : NSString
    var cityMpg : NSString
    var highwayMpg : NSString
    var transmission: NSString
    var year: NSNumber
    var cylinders: NSString
    var driveType: NSString
    var msrp: NSNumber
    var marketClass : NSString
    var vehicleType : NSNumber
    var sellingPrice: NSNumber
    var internetPrice: NSNumber
    var stockNumber: NSString
    var dateInStock: NSDate
    var millage : NSString
    var styleName : NSString
    var styleId : NSString
    var doors : NSNumber
    var driverType : NSNumber?
    var bodyType : NSString
    var locationId : NSNumber

    init(
        vin : NSString,
        vehicleId : NSNumber,
        make : NSString,
        model : NSString,
        body : NSString,
        engine: NSString,
        trim:NSString,
        fuelType : NSString,
        cityMpg : NSString,
        highwayMpg : NSString,
        transmission: NSString,
        year: NSNumber,
        cylinders: NSString,
        driveType: NSString,
        msrp: NSNumber,
        marketClass : NSString,
        vehicleType : NSNumber,
        sellingPrice: NSNumber,
        internetPrice: NSNumber,
        stockNumber: NSString,
        dateInStock: NSDate,
        millage : NSString,
        styleName : NSString,
        styleId : NSString,
        doors : NSNumber,
        bodyType : NSString,
        locationId : NSNumber
        )
    {
        self.vin = vin
        self.vehicleId = vehicleId
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.body = body
        self.engine = engine
        self.trim = trim
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.cityMpg  = cityMpg
        self.highwayMpg = highwayMpg
        self.transmission = transmission
        self.year = year
        self.cylinders = cylinders
        self.driveType = driveType
        self.msrp = msrp
        self.marketClass = marketClass
        self.vehicleType = vehicleType
        self.sellingPrice = sellingPrice
        self.internetPrice = internetPrice
        self.stockNumber = stockNumber
        self.dateInStock = dateInStock
        self.millage = millage
        self.styleName = styleName
        self.styleId = styleId
        self.doors = doors
        self.bodyType = bodyType
        self.locationId = locationId
    }
}
```

And I use this class as follows:

```
func createVehicleAddEditParams(vehicleUpdateRequest : VehicleDetailsUpdateRequest) -> [String: AnyObject]
    {
        let params : [String: AnyObject] =
        [
            "VIN":vehicleUpdateRequest.vin,
            "VehicleId":vehicleUpdateRequest.vehicleId,
            "Make":vehicleUpdateRequest.make,
            "Model":vehicleUpdateRequest.model,
            "Body":vehicleUpdateRequest.body,
            "Engine":vehicleUpdateRequest.engine,
            "Trim":vehicleUpdateRequest.trim,
            "FuelType":vehicleUpdateRequest.fuelType,
            "CityMpg":vehicleUpdateRequest.cityMpg,
            "HwyMpg":vehicleUpdateRequest.highwayMpg,
            "Transmission":vehicleUpdateRequest.transmission,
            "Year":vehicleUpdateRequest.year,
            "Cylinders":vehicleUpdateRequest.cylinders,
            "DriveType":vehicleUpdateRequest.driveType,
            "MSRP":vehicleUpdateRequest.msrp,
            "MarketClass":vehicleUpdateRequest.marketClass,
            "Styles":"",
            "VehicleType":vehicleUpdateRequest.vehicleType,
            "SellingPrice":vehicleUpdateRequest.sellingPrice,
            "InternetPrice":vehicleUpdateRequest.internetPrice,
            "StockNumber":vehicleUpdateRequest.stockNumber,
            "DateInStock":vehicleUpdateRequest.dateInStock,
            "Millage":vehicleUpdateRequest.millage,
            "Certified":0,
            "StyleName":vehicleUpdateRequest.styleName,
            "StyleId":vehicleUpdateRequest.styleId,
            "Doors":vehicleUpdateRequest.doors,
            "DriverType":"",
            "BodyType":vehicleUpdateRequest.bodyType,
            "VehicleImages":[],
            "LocationId":vehicleUpdateRequest.locationId,
            "Options":""
        ]

        return params
    }
```

If I comment(params creation part) this above code this issue goes away. Anyone see anything odd here?

Comment: Can you branch off a pre-migrated commit, let Xcode do an automatic migration to 1.2, then see if compile time improves and compare what's different?

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the same issue. It stops @ the same file.

Comment: Can you let us know which file it stops at? Maybe there is something in that file that will stand out. I took a look at your project but there was too much code for me to realistically examine.

Comment: @user2194039 I edited my questions with the code where it get stuck. Can you please check whether you anything fishy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many R&D steps I found the solutions for the above issue. I converted all the NSString variables to String type variables.

Now my class looks like below:

```
import Foundation

class VehicleDetailsUpdateRequest
{
    var vin : String
    var vehicleId : NSNumber
    var make : String
    var model : String
    var body : String
    var engine: String
    var trim:String
    var fuelType : String
    var cityMpg : String
    var highwayMpg : String
    var transmission: String
    var year: NSNumber
    var cylinders: String
    var driveType: String
    var msrp: NSNumber
    var marketClass : String
    var vehicleType : NSNumber
    var sellingPrice: NSNumber
    var internetPrice: NSNumber
    var stockNumber: String
    var dateInStock: NSDate
    var millage : String
    var styleName : String
    var styleId : String
    var doors : NSNumber
    var driverType : NSNumber?
    var bodyType : String
    var locationId : NSNumber

    init(
        vin : String,
        vehicleId : NSNumber,
        make : String,
        model : String,
        body : String,
        engine: String,
        trim: String,
        fuelType : String,
        cityMpg : String,
        highwayMpg : String,
        transmission: String,
        year: NSNumber,
        cylinders: String,
        driveType: String,
        msrp: NSNumber,
        marketClass : String,
        vehicleType : NSNumber,
        sellingPrice: NSNumber,
        internetPrice: NSNumber,
        stockNumber: String,
        dateInStock: NSDate,
        millage : String,
        styleName : String,
        styleId : String,
        doors : NSNumber,
        bodyType : String,
        locationId : NSNumber
        )
    {
        self.vin = vin
        self.vehicleId = vehicleId
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.body = body
        self.engine = engine
        self.trim = trim
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.cityMpg  = cityMpg
        self.highwayMpg = highwayMpg
        self.transmission = transmission
        self.year = year
        self.cylinders = cylinders
        self.driveType = driveType
        self.msrp = msrp
        self.marketClass = marketClass
        self.vehicleType = vehicleType
        self.sellingPrice = sellingPrice
        self.internetPrice = internetPrice
        self.stockNumber = stockNumber
        self.dateInStock = dateInStock
        self.millage = millage
        self.styleName = styleName
        self.styleId = styleId
        self.doors = doors
        self.bodyType = bodyType
        self.locationId = locationId
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you all in some way.

Comment: Very interesting. Changing the `NSString`s to `String`s is the only thing you changed?

Comment: @user2194039 - I was breaking down the code which was giving me this specific issue and finally I came to that parameter creation function and I kept changing the things I suspected. **NSString -> String** change was the change which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the reason, but my suggestion would be to copy all of your code, and make a new project.  I'm guessing something got converted incorrectly, but initializing a new project should give you a new starting point.

If you don't want to do that, another suggestion would be to Clean your Project and your Test Cases.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. I tried it by cleaning the project several times and no luck :(. I converted all the code files manually. Do you think that I can fix it by creating a new project?

Comment: I tried adding all the files to a new project which was created using xCode 6.4 but it also has the same issue.